# how to read the select statement value as a string in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SELECT LEFT(tblname, LEN(tblname) - 1) as col 
FROM (SELECT column_name + ',' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='Cust_split' 
FOR XML PATH ('')) c (tblname)
```

The result of this query is col1,col2,col3 like this.
How can i read this value in C# as string ? Or is there any other way to read columns for a particular table as a string like col1,col2,col3 in c#.

Comment: have you tried `getString()` method

Comment: No. im new to c# scripting. It will be greatfull if i get the script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using SqlDataReader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete code will be as follow

```
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("your Connection string here");
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("your SQL Query here",con);
        using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
          if(rdr.HasRows)
          {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string myString = rdr.GetString(0); //The 0 stands for "the 0'th column", so the first column of the result.
                (or)
                 string myString= rdr["ColumnName"].ToString();
            }
    }

}
```

using executeScalar. ExecuteScalar is a handy function when you want to just need one Cell value i.e. one column and one row.

```
   SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("your Connection string here");
   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("your SQL Query here",con);
   object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   if (o != null)
   {
      string str= o.ToString();
   }
```

Comment: There is no need in `SqlDataReader` in OP's case as he returns only one string via `select ... for xml`. `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` will be pretty enough.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thank you for notifying. I haven't seen that he returns only one column

Comment: Thank you so much for quick responce vallabha,by using getstring() its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) according to your connection string, then create [SqlConnamd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) having your query as text, open connection, call`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`, and it will return than xml string. And don't forget to close connection and dispose it when it will not be needed no more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Responce. Im able to run the query. But i'm not able to capture that result to a string.

Comment: @sumasreeammu Show your actual code, as it's not clear where the fault is.